# Use max()/min() inside of CSS calc()

Tags: css

Is it possible to use `max()` or `min()` inside of a `calc()` statement in normal css?

i.e:

```
.myclass{
  height: calc(100vh-max(40px, 7vmin));
}
```

Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Also, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc()) says _"The + and - operators must be surrounded by whitespace"_. So it should be `calc(100vh - max(40px, 7vmin))`

Comment: whitespace was the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, yes you can.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max()

> You can (and often need to) combine `min()` and `max()` values, or use `max()` within a `clamp()` or `calc()` function.

If your current expression isn't working, I think it's because you need inner whitespace so the CSS tokenizer can separate the different components, as it's possible `100vh-max` is being interpreted as a single token instead of as `100vh - max(...)`.

Try this:

```
.myclass{
  height: calc( 100vh - max( 40px, 7vmin ) );
}
```

(and I'm sure you'll agree it's easier to read with inner whitespace too).